# How to correctly set X axis values to D3 chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, axis

I have implemented a line chart using D3 and it should show the number of employees in each country over 5 years. I have attached the JSFiddle below. In the X axis of the chart, I need to have the Years as the label. (Year is coming from the data set) But the problem is X axis have some additional values as labels and I couldn't figure out why it is happening. I'm also quite new to using D3. Can someone tell me what's wrong here?

Fiddle : [https://jsfiddle.net/yasirunilan/e01L3uvt/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/yasirunilan/tz57wc29/9/)

```
var data = [
        {
            name: "USA",
            values: [
                {date: "2000", price: "100"},
                {date: "2001", price: "110"},
                {date: "2002", price: "145"},
                {date: "2003", price: "241"},
                {date: "2004", price: "101"}
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "UK",
            values: [
                {date: "2000", price: "200"},
                {date: "2001", price: "120"},
                {date: "2002", price: "33"},
                {date: "2003", price: "21"},
                {date: "2004", price: "51"}
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "UAE",
            values: [
                {date: "2000", price: "50"},
                {date: "2001", price: "10"},
                {date: "2002", price: "5"},
                {date: "2003", price: "71"},
                {date: "2004", price: "20"}
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "Australia",
            values: [
                {date: "2000", price: "20"},
                {date: "2001", price: "40"},
                {date: "2002", price: "25"},
                {date: "2003", price: "75"},
                {date: "2004", price: "19"}
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "India",
            values: [
                {date: "2000", price: "200"},
                {date: "2001", price: "150"},
                {date: "2002", price: "170"},
                {date: "2003", price: "150"},
                {date: "2004", price: "130"}
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "Orange Department F",
            values: [
                {date: "2000", price: "75"},
                {date: "2001", price: "100"},
                {date: "2002", price: "120"},
                {date: "2003", price: "140"},
                {date: "2004", price: "190"}
            ]
        }
    ];

    const margin = 80;
    const width = 1000 - 2 * margin;
    const height = 550 - 2 * margin;

    var duration = 250;

    var lineOpacity = "0.25";
    var lineOpacityHover = "0.85";
    var otherLinesOpacityHover = "0.1";
    var lineStroke = "1.5px";
    var lineStrokeHover = "2.5px";

    var circleOpacity = '0.85';
    var circleOpacityOnLineHover = "0.25"
    var circleRadius = 3;
    var circleRadiusHover = 6;


    /* Format Data */
    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y");
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.values.forEach(function(d) {
            d.date = parseDate.parse(d.date);
            d.price = +d.price;
        });
    });

    /* Scale */
    var xScale = d3.time.scale()
        .domain(d3.extent(data[0].values, d => d.date))
        .range([0, width-margin]);
    var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data[0].values, d => d.price)])
        .range([height-margin, 0]);

    // var color = d3.scale.ordinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
    var color = d3.scale.category10();

    /* Add SVG */
    var svg = d3.select("svg")
        .attr("width", (width+margin)+"px")
        .attr("height", (height+margin)+"px")
        .append('g')
        .attr("transform", `translate(${margin}, ${margin})`);


    /* Add line into SVG */
    var line = d3.svg.line()
        .x(d => xScale(d.date))
        .y(d => yScale(d.price));

    let lines = svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'lines');

    lines.selectAll('.line-group')
        .data(data).enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'line-group')
        .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
            svg.append("text")
                .attr("class", "title-text")
                .style("fill", color(i))
                .text(d.name)
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("x", (width-margin)/2)
                .attr("y", 5);
        })
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {
            svg.select(".title-text").remove();
        })
        .append('path')
        .attr('class', 'line')
        .attr('d', d => line(d.values))
        .style('stroke', (d, i) => color(i))
        .style('opacity', lineOpacity)
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {
            d3.selectAll('.line')
                .style('opacity', otherLinesOpacityHover);
            d3.selectAll('.circle')
                .style('opacity', circleOpacityOnLineHover);
            d3.select(this)
                .style('opacity', lineOpacityHover)
                .style("stroke-width", lineStrokeHover)
                .style("cursor", "pointer");
        })
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {
            d3.selectAll(".line")
                .style('opacity', lineOpacity);
            d3.selectAll('.circle')
                .style('opacity', circleOpacity);
            d3.select(this)
                .style("stroke-width", lineStroke)
                .style("cursor", "none");
        });


    /* Add circles in the line */
    lines.selectAll("circle-group")
        .data(data).enter()
        .append("g")
        .style("fill", (d, i) => color(i))
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(d => d.values).enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "circle")
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {
            d3.select(this)
                .style("cursor", "pointer")
                .append("text")
                .attr("class", "text")
                .text(`${d.price}`)
                .attr("x", d => xScale(d.date) + 5)
                .attr("y", d => yScale(d.price) - 10);
        })
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {
            d3.select(this)
                .style("cursor", "none")
                .transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .selectAll(".text").remove();
        })
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", d => xScale(d.date))
        .attr("cy", d => yScale(d.price))
        .attr("r", circleRadius)
        .style('opacity', circleOpacity)
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {
            d3.select(this)
                .transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr("r", circleRadiusHover);
        })
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {
            d3.select(this)
                .transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr("r", circleRadius);
        });

    /* Add Axis into SVG */
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale)
        .orient("bottom").tickSize(1);

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale)
        .orient("left").tickSize(1);
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height-margin})`)
        .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
        .append('text')
        .attr("y", 15)
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("fill", "#000")
        .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
        .text("No. of Employees");
```

Comment: why use d3v3 when you are learning d3, we are at d3v5 at the moment. With d3v5 you can specify that you only want ticks at the year marks. Why don't you combine your mouse event handlers?

Comment: the system that I'm implementing the charts uses d3 V3 already. As it's better to use the same library version I implemented this using D3v3. Can't we do it in v3. And for what exactly you asked to combine mouse event handlers?

Comment: then implement a custom tick formatter like https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format

Answer (score 0):

Here I have changed the `tickFormat` of xAxis to

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale)
            .orient("bottom").ticks(5).tickFormat(function(d) {
              if (d % 1 == 0) {
                return d3.format('.f')(d)
              } else {
                return ""
              }
            }).tickSize(1);
```

Below is the full working demo of source code and it worked. Hope it helps you.

```js
var data = [
            {
                name: "USA",
                values: [
                    {date: "2000", price: "100"},
                    {date: "2001", price: "110"},
                    {date: "2002", price: "145"},
                    {date: "2003", price: "241"},
                    {date: "2004", price: "101"}
                ]
            },
            {
                name: "UK",
                values: [
                    {date: "2000", price: "200"},
                    {date: "2001", price: "120"},
                    {date: "2002", price: "33"},
                    {date: "2003", price: "21"},
                    {date: "2004", price: "51"}
                ]
            },
            {
                name: "UAE",
                values: [
                    {date: "2000", price: "50"},
                    {date: "2001", price: "10"},
                    {date: "2002", price: "5"},
                    {date: "2003", price: "71"},
                    {date: "2004", price: "20"}
                ]
            },
            {
                name: "Australia",
                values: [
                    {date: "2000", price: "20"},
                    {date: "2001", price: "40"},
                    {date: "2002", price: "25"},
                    {date: "2003", price: "75"},
                    {date: "2004", price: "19"}
                ]
            },
            {
                name: "India",
                values: [
                    {date: "2000", price: "200"},
                    {date: "2001", price: "150"},
                    {date: "2002", price: "170"},
                    {date: "2003", price: "150"},
                    {date: "2004", price: "130"}
                ]
            },
            {
                name: "Orange Department F",
                values: [
                    {date: "2000", price: "75"},
                    {date: "2001", price: "100"},
                    {date: "2002", price: "120"},
                    {date: "2003", price: "140"},
                    {date: "2004", price: "190"}
                ]
            }
        ];

        const margin = 80;
        const width = 1000 - 2 * margin;
        const height = 550 - 2 * margin;

        var duration = 250;

        var lineOpacity = "0.25";
        var lineOpacityHover = "0.85";
        var otherLinesOpacityHover = "0.1";
        var lineStroke = "1.5px";
        var lineStrokeHover = "2.5px";

        var circleOpacity = '0.85';
        var circleOpacityOnLineHover = "0.25"
        var circleRadius = 3;
        var circleRadiusHover = 6;


        /* Format Data */
        var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y");
        data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.values.forEach(function(d) {
               // d.date = parseDate.parse(d.date);
                d.price = +d.price;
            });
        });

   //console.log(data);

    //console.log(d3.extent(data[0].values, d => d.date));
        /* Scale */
        var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain(d3.extent(data[0].values, d => d.date))
            .range([0, width-margin]);
            
        var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(data[0].values, d => d.price)])
            .range([height-margin, 0]);

        // var color = d3.scale.ordinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
        var color = d3.scale.category10();

        /* Add SVG */
        var svg = d3.select("svg")
            .attr("width", (width+margin)+"px")
            .attr("height", (height+margin)+"px")
            .append('g')
            .attr("transform", `translate(${margin}, ${margin})`);


        /* Add line into SVG */
        var line = d3.svg.line()
            .x(d => xScale(d.date))
            .y(d => yScale(d.price));

        let lines = svg.append('g')
            .attr('class', 'lines');

        lines.selectAll('.line-group')
            .data(data).enter()
            .append('g')
            .attr('class', 'line-group')
            .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
                svg.append("text")
                    .attr("class", "title-text")
                    .style("fill", color(i))
                    .text(d.name)
                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                    .attr("x", (width-margin)/2)
                    .attr("y", 5);
            })
            .on("mouseout", function(d) {
                svg.select(".title-text").remove();
            })
            .append('path')
            .attr('class', 'line')
            .attr('d', d => line(d.values))
            .style('stroke', (d, i) => color(i))
            .style('opacity', lineOpacity)
            .on("mouseover", function(d) {
                d3.selectAll('.line')
                    .style('opacity', otherLinesOpacityHover);
                d3.selectAll('.circle')
                    .style('opacity', circleOpacityOnLineHover);
                d3.select(this)
                    .style('opacity', lineOpacityHover)
                    .style("stroke-width", lineStrokeHover)
                    .style("cursor", "pointer");
            })
            .on("mouseout", function(d) {
                d3.selectAll(".line")
                    .style('opacity', lineOpacity);
                d3.selectAll('.circle')
                    .style('opacity', circleOpacity);
                d3.select(this)
                    .style("stroke-width", lineStroke)
                    .style("cursor", "none");
            });


        /* Add circles in the line */
        lines.selectAll("circle-group")
            .data(data).enter()
            .append("g")
            .style("fill", (d, i) => color(i))
            .selectAll("circle")
            .data(d => d.values).enter()
            .append("g")
            .attr("class", "circle")
            .on("mouseover", function(d) {
                d3.select(this)
                    .style("cursor", "pointer")
                    .append("text")
                    .attr("class", "text")
                    .text(`${d.price}`)
                    .attr("x", d => xScale(d.date) + 5)
                    .attr("y", d => yScale(d.price) - 10);
            })
            .on("mouseout", function(d) {
                d3.select(this)
                    .style("cursor", "none")
                    .transition()
                    .duration(duration)
                    .selectAll(".text").remove();
            })
            .append("circle")
            .attr("cx", d => xScale(d.date))
            .attr("cy", d => yScale(d.price))
            .attr("r", circleRadius)
            .style('opacity', circleOpacity)
            .on("mouseover", function(d) {
                d3.select(this)
                    .transition()
                    .duration(duration)
                    .attr("r", circleRadiusHover);
            })
            .on("mouseout", function(d) {
                d3.select(this)
                    .transition()
                    .duration(duration)
                    .attr("r", circleRadius);
            });

        /* Add Axis into SVG */
        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale)
            .orient("bottom").ticks(5).tickFormat(function(d) {
              if (d % 1 == 0) {
                return d3.format('.f')(d)
              } else {
                return ""
              }
            }).tickSize(1);

        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale)
            .orient("left").tickSize(1);
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height-margin})`)
            .call(xAxis);

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis)
            .append('text')
            .attr("y", 15)
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("fill", "#000")
            .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
            .text("No. of Employees");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.10/d3.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: not a generic solution is the number of years change. or if the size of the chart changes

Comment: @rioV8 I am sorry! I didn't get you. Can you please explain a bit?

Comment: `d%1 == 0` is not applicable to all number of years, it is always true because you set the number of ticks and you have a linear x scale, Question is:  x is a time scale not a linear scale, we need to handle generic time values but only show year ticks. This is a workaround for only this input case.

Answer (score 0):

For this one, I found a solution by changing the tick formatting. Now it works as intended. Following code shows the sample code with correct behavior.

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/yasirunilan/tz57wc29/13/

```
var data = [
        {
            name: "USA",
            values: [
                {date: "2000", price: "100"},
                {date: "2001", price: "110"},
                {date: "2002", price: "145"},
                {date: "2003", price: "241"},
                {date: "2004", price: "101"}
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "UK",
            values: [
                {date: "2000", price: "200"},
                {date: "2001", price: "120"},
                {date: "2002", price: "33"},
                {date: "2003", price: "21"},
                {date: "2004", price: "51"}
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "India",
            values: [
                {date: "2000", price: "50"},
                {date: "2001", price: "10"},
                {date: "2002", price: "5"},
                {date: "2003", price: "71"},
                {date: "2004", price: "20"}
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "Australia",
            values: [
                {date: "2000", price: "20"},
                {date: "2001", price: "40"},
                {date: "2002", price: "25"},
                {date: "2003", price: "75"},
                {date: "2004", price: "19"}
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "UAE",
            values: [
                {date: "2000", price: "200"},
                {date: "2001", price: "150"},
                {date: "2002", price: "170"},
                {date: "2003", price: "150"},
                {date: "2004", price: "130"}
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "China",
            values: [
                {date: "2000", price: "75"},
                {date: "2001", price: "100"},
                {date: "2002", price: "120"},
                {date: "2003", price: "140"},
                {date: "2004", price: "190"}
            ]
        }
    ];

    const margin = 80;
    const width = 1000 - 2 * margin;
    const height = 550 - 2 * margin;

    var duration = 250;

    var lineOpacity = "0.25";
    var lineOpacityHover = "0.85";
    var otherLinesOpacityHover = "0.1";
    var lineStroke = "1.5px";
    var lineStrokeHover = "2.5px";

    var circleOpacity = '0.85';
    var circleOpacityOnLineHover = "0.25"
    var circleRadius = 3;
    var circleRadiusHover = 6;


    /* Format Data */
    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y");
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.values.forEach(function(d) {
            d.date = parseDate.parse(d.date);
            d.price = +d.price;
        });
    });

    /* Scale */
    var xScale = d3.time.scale()
        .domain(d3.extent(data[0].values, d => d.date))
        .range([0, width-margin]);
    var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data[0].values, d => d.price)])
        .range([height-margin, 0]);

    // var color = d3.scale.ordinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
    var color = d3.scale.category10();

    /* Add SVG */
    var svg = d3.select("svg")
        .attr("width", (width+margin)+"px")
        .attr("height", (height+margin)+"px")
        .append('g')
        .attr("transform", `translate(${margin}, ${margin})`);


    /* Add line into SVG */
    var line = d3.svg.line()
        .x(d => xScale(d.date))
        .y(d => yScale(d.price));

    let lines = svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'lines');

    lines.selectAll('.line-group')
        .data(data).enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'line-group')
        .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
            svg.append("text")
                .attr("class", "title-text")
                .style("fill", color(i))
                .text(d.name)
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("x", (width-margin)/2)
                .attr("y", 5);
        })
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {
            svg.select(".title-text").remove();
        })
        .append('path')
        .attr('class', 'line')
        .attr('d', d => line(d.values))
        .style('stroke', (d, i) => color(i))
        .style('opacity', lineOpacity)
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {
            d3.selectAll('.line')
                .style('opacity', otherLinesOpacityHover);
            d3.selectAll('.circle')
                .style('opacity', circleOpacityOnLineHover);
            d3.select(this)
                .style('opacity', lineOpacityHover)
                .style("stroke-width", lineStrokeHover)
                .style("cursor", "pointer");
        })
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {
            d3.selectAll(".line")
                .style('opacity', lineOpacity);
            d3.selectAll('.circle')
                .style('opacity', circleOpacity);
            d3.select(this)
                .style("stroke-width", lineStroke)
                .style("cursor", "none");
        });


    /* Add circles in the line */
    lines.selectAll("circle-group")
        .data(data).enter()
        .append("g")
        .style("fill", (d, i) => color(i))
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(d => d.values).enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "circle")
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {
            d3.select(this)
                .style("cursor", "pointer")
                .append("text")
                .attr("class", "text")
                .text(`${d.price}`)
                .attr("x", d => xScale(d.date) + 5)
                .attr("y", d => yScale(d.price) - 10);
        })
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {
            d3.select(this)
                .style("cursor", "none")
                .transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .selectAll(".text").remove();
        })
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", d => xScale(d.date))
        .attr("cy", d => yScale(d.price))
        .attr("r", circleRadius)
        .style('opacity', circleOpacity)
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {
            d3.select(this)
                .transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr("r", circleRadiusHover);
        })
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {
            d3.select(this)
                .transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr("r", circleRadius);
        });



    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale)
        .orient("bottom").tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y")).tickSize(1);

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale)
        .orient("left").tickSize(1);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height-margin})`)
        .call(xAxis.ticks(d3.time.year));

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
        .append('text')
        .attr("y", 15)
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("fill", "#000")
        .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
        .text("No. of Employees");
```